# Why is "_csrf" attribute not resolved inside spring-boot velocity view <head> tags?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, velocity

I have a Spring-Boot project with Velocity templating all configured and working fine...

In my velocity view, I have the following;

```
<head>
    <!-- some other meta tags here -->

    <meta name="csrf-token" content="$!_csrf.token">
</head>
```

Here's what the output looks like when I inspect in chrome;

`<meta name="csrf-token" content="$!_csrf.token">`

---

However on this same page I have a form that looks something like this;

```
<form method="post" action="/post/to/wherever">
    <input type="hidden" id="csrf" name="$!_csrf.parameterName" value="$!_csrf.token" data-header="$!_csrf.headerName"/>

    <!-- other fields here -->

</form>
```

And the browser inspection shows the following;

`<input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="69799b81-7c45-4042-9269-3a83769df682" data-header="X-CSRF-TOKEN">`

So obviously, the **_csrf** attribute gets injected and resolved within the **form** body but not within the **head** meta tags.

***QUESTION:*** What would cause a thing like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I eventually found out that what was happening here was due to a very simple oversight.

I had the `<head>...</head>` section in a separate template and was including it to other templates as follows;

```
#include("/pages/common/header.vm")
```

Well, for users of velocity, it's quite obvious that the above just includes the template as-is (i.e all content is translated as text) and wouldn't resolve any velocity context attributes declared within. So I just needed to change it to the following

```
#parse("/pages/common/header.vm")
```

This ensures that any velocity attributes declared within the `header.vm` template are appropriately parsed and the values accordingly read.

I was initially going to delete the question thinking it shouldn't have been asked in the first place, but I realized, well this is ***StackOverflow***, better to just point out the mistake and save somebody else some little time. Essentially, make the world a better place for everyone... Cheers!